# Eclipse on the Mac... using Windows keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'm a power Eclipse user on Linux/Windows, and the keyboard shortcuts are practically muscle memory. Just recently started developing on a Mac (love it!), using Eclipse, but was really tripped up by the use of the `command` key... and not all the shortcuts map over consistently.

I've already re-mapped all my common shortcuts to use `Ctrl`, but was wondering if anyone's found a more efficient and complete way to do this? Has some kind soul gone through all the shortcuts and posted a preferences file ready for import?

Comment: Would you mind posting your mapping somewhere?  I would be willing to work on it and share our combined results.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the command key,

[alt text http://www.pajbam.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/organize_imports-menu_item.png](http://www.pajbam.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/organize_imports-menu_item.png)

, may be this [article **Mac Keys for Eclipse**](http://www.martinkahr.com/2006/02/13/mac-keys-for-eclipse/) might contains a [preference file](http://www.martinkahr.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/02/eclipse-mac-keys.epf.zip) (to be imported) with interesting shortcuts.

(Save your current preferences first ;) )

Answer (score 6):

I have the same case... Mac is only something temporary for me to test some things, and while at it, it really annoys me that I cannot use the keybindings available on Linux/Windows (and with the short sessions, it's worthless trying to retrain my muscles), so, if someone does have a preference file for that, I'd appreciate it too.

---

Edit: Just found out:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/remap-home-and-end-to-beginning-and-end-of-line

and remapping things globally helps a lot (and for Eclipse itself I just went on and edited the missing bindings manually -- after having the system ones already fixed).

Comment: Pity that Eclipse (and most Java apps) ignore these settings.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when switching. While this does not answer your direct question, I would really recommend you to learn the Mac shortcuts.

The command key on a Mac is located better than Ctrl key, and pressing it causes less stress for your hand. After many years of developments I gradually start to feel pain in my hands, and I know (feel) that key placement matters — so save your health while it's fine.

The following mapping table might help you:

- Ctrl -> Command (obviously)
- Ctrl-Shift -> Command-Option (aka Command-Alt)
- Alt-Shift -> no change (Option-Shift)

Today, even when I switch between Mac and Windows, I still have no problem with shortcuts. Turns out Mac and Windows Eclipse shortcuts can be different kinds of muscle memory.

Also I have once drawn a set of keyboard pictures with various Mac Eclipse shortcuts, available at [www.tarantsov.com/eclipse/shortcuts-illustrated/](http://www.tarantsov.com/eclipse/shortcuts-illustrated/) — maybe this can help you too.

Comment: The trouble is developing on Windows with Eclipse or Linux you have to use different key bindings, this really messes with muscle memory and the fact that it's a cross-platform application. I really wish there was a "Windows/Linux" key binding mode like there is an emacs key binding mode.

Comment: I think you're approaching the key mappings by thinking of the names (Alt-Shift = no change) where the original author (and myself) are more concerned with muscle memory. So positionally, ALT-Shift on Windows would be no change if it was Command-Shift on Mac, since Alt and Command are the keys that are right beside the space bar.

Comment: @SteveArmstrong: try it on a Macbook where you also have to press fn along with the shortcut.  For example, run is CTRL+F11 on Windows, but to do the same on a Macbook you also have to hit fn at the same time.

Comment: As long-time windows and short time mac user. I would definitely recommend learning basic mac style text editing shortcuts, simply because it is mac and it is similar in all mac editor. BUT Eclipse is an IDE what need app specific shortcut. There would be no need to be different in mac or win. My favorite always "driving me crazy" example is. CTR+h (win). And by following "intuition" it would he Command+H. What is a sys global shortcut and hiding active window :)

Comment: "While this does not answer" indeed. And, worse, the "Mac way" is to use a file `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and while this works in all applications, it seems Java-based applications don't seem to bother. For my case I work in a mixed VMWare/Windows and Mac environment, and even though I am familiar with the Mac keys, muscle memory trumps all else.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should do the trick
In your Eclipse for Windows machine

Use: File->export->General and select 'Keys Preferences'

and import that file to your Eclipse for Mac

File -> import -> General

Answer (score 0):

I Strongly recommend you to go with the flow regarding to mac shortcuts. I am a windows user who switch to Linux and recently to Mac. i use eclipse in and most commands that involves ctrl are just change to command like:
command + c and command + v for copy and paste. And Command + Shift + r to replace.
Command + B to build all.
and of course FN + F5 to refresh. Besides Mac shorcuts usually work for almost all mac apps so dont waste your time switching every app to be windows like because you just focus on what mac/os is missing instead of enjoying new ways to use you computer.

Comment: This doesn't always apply.  I do windows, mac, and linux development on my Macs.  I use visual studio, x-code, eclipse etc.  The Mac keyboard shortcuts are annoying at best.  Why would I want to jump to the top of the file when I press 'home'?  99% of the time I only want to go to the front of the line of code - windows/linux dev tools get this right.